# footmisc's para option and margins

Tags: margins, footmisc

I've been having problems trying to combine `footmisc`'s `para` option with margins. EDIT: After @marmot's suggestions, I've tried the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4,11pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[para]{footmisc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\tikz[overlay,remember picture]{\draw[red,latex-latex] (2,0 |-current page.south) -- ++(0,1.5)
node[midway,fill=white,font=\sffamily]{1.5cm};}
\lipsum[1-5]
\footnote{AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA}\footnote{AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA}\footnote{AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA}\footnote{AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA}\footnote{AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA}
\lipsum[10-15]
\end{document}
```

The result I get is the following:
[image: error image example]

When compiling, I get `Underfull hbox` errors. Is there a work around to enforce the margins?

Comment: I confirm that this *new* example has the issue (in addition to the *many* `Underfull \hbox ` warnings). Do you have the issue with your first example on your machine, or does it produce the same output as in my answer? I am not an expert on this, but I am not too surprised to see that some of the margins are not exactly respected if the code spits out tons of warnings. If you place a tabular that is too high, or a minipage, the same thing will happen. Do you have an example where this happens and there are no warnings?

Comment: The original code was working fine (I was trying to obtain a minimal example of what I meant). I've updated the example again, it only has two underfull errors, but the problem persists.

Comment: As I said, I am not an expert, but I can easily provide an example with only one warning that is *really* messed up: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|}
x\\[40 cm]
y
\end{tabular}
\end{document}`. Personally I think one has to resolve the warnings first, and if something bad happens without warning, then this is a real issue.

Comment: Yes, but still, I would like to that those footnotes and the marging respected. Isn't there a way to enforce the margins? If I remove the `para` option, everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to TeX.SE! I cannot confirm your observation. Could you please compile

```
\documentclass[a4,11pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[para]{footmisc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\tikz[overlay,remember picture]{\draw[red,latex-latex] (2,0 |-current page.south) -- ++(0,1.5)
node[midway,fill=white,font=\sffamily]{1.5cm};}
\lipsum[1-5]\footnote{\lipsum[6-9]}\lipsum[10-15]
\end{document}
```

and see what you get? I get

[image]

so there is a distance between the bottom border of the page and the base of the lowest line of precisely `1.5cm`. What do you get?

Comment: I've edited my question with an example, thanks for the tikz idea!